# Why is Internal memory in java Native Memory Tracking increasing

Tags: java, docker, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, kubernetes

My application is running in a docker container, it use scala and use "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)", its Xmx is set to be 16GB and container memory limit is 24Gb, after running for some time the container is killed:

```
Last State:         Terminated
  Reason:           OOMKilled
  Exit Code:        137
```

However I can't find any "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" errors in the log, not even once in last 2 weeks in all 48 nodes. So it's not likely a normal heap OOM.

dmesg output:

```
$ dmesg -l err,crit,alert,emerg
STDIN is not a terminal
[1647254.978515] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 10924 (java) score 1652 or sacrifice child
[1647254.989138] Killed process 10924 (java) total-vm:34187148kB, anon-rss:24853120kB, file-rss:23904kB
[1655749.664871] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 1969 (java) score 1652 or sacrifice child
[1655749.675513] Killed process 1969 (java) total-vm:35201940kB, anon-rss:24856624kB, file-rss:24120kB
[1655749.987605] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 2799 (java) score 1656 or sacrifice child
```

I then run JCMD multiple times before it is killed again and the data looks like the following:
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=25505339KB, committed=25140947KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=16777216KB, committed=16777216KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=16777216KB, committed=16777216KB)

- Class (reserved=247996KB, committed=93500KB)
                          (classes #14539)
                          (malloc=2236KB #29794)
                          (mmap: reserved=245760KB, committed=91264KB)
- Thread (reserved=1013160KB, committed=1013160KB)
                          (thread #1902)
                          (stack: reserved=1003956KB, committed=1003956KB)
                          (malloc=6240KB #9523)
                          (arena=2964KB #3803)
- Code (reserved=263255KB, committed=86131KB)
                          (malloc=13655KB #20964)
                          (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=72476KB)
- GC (reserved=776174KB, committed=776174KB)
                          (malloc=120814KB #164310)
                          (mmap: reserved=655360KB, committed=655360KB)
- Compiler (reserved=812KB, committed=812KB)
                          (malloc=681KB #1823)
                          (arena=131KB #3)
- Internal (reserved=6366260KB, committed=6366256KB)
                          (malloc=6366256KB #178778)
                          (mmap: reserved=4KB, committed=0KB)
- Symbol (reserved=18391KB, committed=18391KB)
                          (malloc=16242KB #153138)
                          (arena=2150KB #1)
- Native Memory Tracking (reserved=9002KB, committed=9002KB)
                          (malloc=186KB #2000)
                          (tracking overhead=8816KB)
- Arena Chunk (reserved=273KB, committed=273KB)
                          (malloc=273KB)
- Unknown (reserved=32800KB, committed=32KB)
                          (mmap: reserved=32800KB, committed=32KB)

One thing I noticed is this section:
Internal (reserved=6366260KB, committed=6366256KB)

It keeps growing and causing total memory usage to exceed 24GB limit.

Anyone has seen similar issue before? and anyone knows what is Internal memory here and what could be the reason that it keeps growing without releasing the memory?

Comment: our application is running in kubernates managed containers, after upgraded to kubernates 1.4 this issue seems to be fixed, not more OOM in all 48 pods in more than 100 hours, even GC runs better. but still can't tell what exactly is causing this yet.

Comment: update again: looks like this is only improved but not solved even after the upgrade, after 8 days there are a few pods run into same issue. so the native memory still increase but at a much slower pace.

Answer (score 4):

Recently Our application met the same problem. In our case, we use netty, and netty allocate direct memory, when many io connnection exists, the internal memory in java Native Memory Tracking increasing.
And finally we use two parameters to limit the native memory.

```
-Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory=1073741824
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not answer to your question, it is just a workaround.

I have observed same problem in docker containers running JRuby on java version "1.8.0_45". The solution was to explicitly invoke Garbage Collection. I have absolutely no idea, why this works, but after GC Internal Java memory returned to 8MB.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` configured?

If *yes*, please remove that.

If *no* "`-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`" configured, how about the situation after triggering a full GC via JConsole

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have run into the issue that I answered here: [Java Heap Dump : How to find the objects/class that is taking memory by 1. io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil 2. byte[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681786/java-heap-dump-how-to-find-the-objects-class-that-is-taking-memory-by-1-io-ne/68727220#68727220)

If you're running on a node with a large number of cores, you may have to set the environment variable `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` to control how native memory is allocated.