# Java Heap Dump : How to find the objects/class that is taking memory by 1. io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil 2. byte[] array

Tags: java, spring-boot, out-of-memory, heap-dump, java-heap

I found that one of my spring boot project's memory (RAM consumption) is increasing day by day. When I uploaded the jar file to the AWS server, it was taking 582 MB of RAM (Max Allocated RAM is 1500 MB), but each day, the RAM is increasing by 50MB to 100 MB and today after 5 days, it's taking 835 MB. Right now the project is having 100-150 users and with normal usage of Rest APIs.

Because of this increase in the RAM, couple of times the application went down with the following error (error found from the logs):

```
Exception in thread "http-nio-3384-ClientPoller" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

So to resolve this, I found that by using JAVA Heap Dump, I can find the objects/classes that are taking the memory. So by using `Jmap` in the command line, I've created a heap dump and uploaded it to [Heap Hero](https://heaphero.io/heap-index.jsp) and [Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/). In both of them I found the following:

**1.** Total Waste memory is: 64.69MB (73%) (check below screenshot)

[image]

**2**. Out of these, 34.06MB is taken by `Byte [] array` and `LinkedHashmap[]` (check below screenshot), which I have never used in my whole project. I searched for it in my project but didn't found.

[image]
**3**. Following 2 large objects taking 32 MB and 20 MB respectively.

```
1. Java Static io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR

2. Java Static com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.connectionFinalizerPhantomRefs`
```

[image]

So I tried to find this netty.buffer. in my project, but I don't find anything which matched with netty or buffer.

Now my question is **how can I reduce this memory leak** or **how can I find the exact memory consumption objects/class/variable** so that I can reduce the heap size.

I know few of the experts will ask for the source code or anything similar to that but I believe that from the heap dump we can **find the memory leak or live objects that are available in the memory**. I am looking for that option or anything that reduces this heap dump!

I am working on this issue for the past 3 weeks. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Something uses the Netty IO framework.  What you are seeing is most likely the buffer cache.  Unless it is growing out of control there is nothing you can do about it.  32MB is not out of control.

Comment: I will suggest one approach. After next recycle or right now, take one heap dump of the "live" objects only. jmap has the option. Once you see heap usage went up after 1-2 days, take another dump similar way. Keep collecting it for few days until it crash. Then compare the object(s) growth across the dumps. MAT can do it. If there is a leak, you should see a growth pattern. Also please remember, dumping the "live" object is the key. 

Happy leak hunting! :)

Comment: @suv3ndu Thank you but the above images and explanation is of live objects. Here is the command that I did use "jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=/home/ubuntu/dump 35" where 35  is my process id

Comment: @KishanSolanki Are those images from the final crash dump? If so, to me, they do not looks like leaking object as you mentioned 50-100MB growth per day. That's why I suggested that approach.

Answer (score 4):

Start with enabling the [JVM native memory tracker](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/vm/native-memory-tracking.html) to get an idea which part of the memory is increasing by adding the flag `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary`. There is some performance overhead according to the documentation (5-10%), but if this isn't a issue I would recommend running the JVM with this flag enabled even in production.

Then you can check the values using `jcmd <PID> VM.native_memory` (there's a good writeup in this answer: [Java native memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756798/java-native-memory-usage))

If there is indeed a big chunk of native memory allocated, it's likely this is allocated by Netty.

How do you run your application in AWS? If it's running in a Docker image, you might have stumbled upon this issue: [What would cause a java process to greatly exceed the Xmx or Xss limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575342/what-would-cause-a-java-process-to-greatly-exceed-the-xmx-or-xss-limit)
If this is the case, you may need to set the environment variable `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` if your application is using native memory (which Netty does) and running on a server with a large number of cores. It's perfectly possible that the JVM allocates this memory for Netty but doesn't see any reason to release it, so it will appear to only continue to grow.

If you want to control how much native memory can be allocated by Netty, you can use the JVM flag `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` for this (I believe the default is the same value as `Xmx`) and lower it in case you application doesn't require that much memory.

JVM memory tuning is a complex process and it becomes even more complex when native memory is involved - as the linked answer shows it's not as easy as simply setting the `Xms` and `Xmx` flag and expecting that no more memory will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Heap dump is not enough to detect memory leaks.
You need to look at the difference of two consecutive heaps snapshots both taken after calling the GC.
Or you need a profiling tool that can give the generations count for each class.
Then you should only look at your domain objects  (not generic objects like bytes or strings ...etc) that survived the GC and passed from the old snapshot to the new one.
Or, if using the profiling tool, look for old domain objects that still alive and growing for many generations.

Having objects lived for many generations and keeps growing means those objects are still refernced and the GC is not able to reclaim them. However, living for many generations alone is not enough to cause a leak because cached or static Objects may stay for many generations. The other important factor is that they keep growing.

After you detected what object is being leaked, you may use heap dumb to analyse those objects and get the references.